# SQL Query Builder Javascript UI

Tags: javascript, sql, user-interface

I'm looking for a UI tool to help users generate SQL queries.

[Red Query Builder](http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/) has some of the features I'd like, but the source doesn't seem to be available in an easily-editable format and it lacks an interface for manipulating `group` or `order` commands.

Digging around the internet didn't reveal any other palatable candidates, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 9):

Some newer options for javascript query builders:

1. https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder
2. https://github.com/sapientglobalmarkets/react-querybuilder
3. https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-client-react#query-builder
4. https://github.com/zebzhao/Angular-QueryBuilder
5. https://github.com/joewalling/react-two-way-querybuilder

Comment: 6. https://github.com/nhabuiduc/react-filter-box
7. https://github.com/komarovalexander/react-filter-control

Answer (score 7):

Another option is [jquery-Querybuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/index.html). I haven't used it yet, but it seems to be a pretty polished, open source solution.

Answer (score 5):

The source is here now https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder

Order by and group by options shouldn't be too difficult to add?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [EasyQuery](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/) .

It's mostly ASP.NET solution but they have a set of jQuery widgets
which include all the functionality you need.
They have recently published and article  which describes how to use
those JavaScript widgets together with PHP backend:
http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/usecase/php-query-builder-with-easyquery

It is free (at least at the moment).

Comment: EasyQuery is not free. I have been using it for several years now.

Answer (score 1):

Even i search for it today and created a list:

1) Query builder
http://aspquerybuilder.net/?_ga=2.150945718.1618902383.1522751533-1013206784.1522751533
price : https://www.activequerybuilder.com/purchase.html

2)  Active query builder
Demo : https://webapi.activequerybuilder.com/Demo
Free to use.

3)  Custom code
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1060170/User-Responsive-Web-Query-Builder-using-ASP-NET

4)  DataSparc: Paid service
Demo : https://www.datasparc.com/dbhawk-online-demo/

5)  Jquery query builder: Free to use.
Demo: http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html
GitHub: https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder

6)  DevExpress.com
Demo : https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/QueryBuilder.aspx
Documentation: https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/DataBinding/QueryBuilderControl.aspx